# Why does "to dip" mean "to leave"?

Tags: american-english, word-usage, slang

So, "dip" has come to mean "leave" in American slang. As in, "Let's dip," i.e. "Let's get out of here."

How did that happen? The best I could come up with is: a dip in the road obscures vision, so if you're in a dip, you can't be seen-- and, if you leave, you can't be seen. That's a bit of a stretch, though.

Anyone have a more plausible explanation?

Comment: Have you ever heard the (older) expressions, *dip out for a bit*, or *dip in for a quick one*? The idea being conveyed is the diversion is *short*, *finite*, *noncommital*, as in a short detour. BTW, in modern slang usage, *dip* isn't just *leave*, but more strongly like *[skeedaddle](https://twitter.com/roach_nigga/status/506955577663422464)*, *getting out of here*.

Comment: Is it simply a shortened "depart" (mispronounced)?

Comment: @DanBron - nope, never heard that expression (US Midwest).

Comment: Do you, as we do, use the verb *duck* to mean lower oneself (particularly) the head quickly - often to avoid something? It is also used with water - to duck (one's head) under. But by extension we talk about *ducking out* of something e.g. an awkward meeting with someone.

Comment: @WS2 If by "you" you mean AmE speakers: then yes, we do.

Comment: The hardest slang words to trace are ones that have multiple standard and slang meanings other than the one in question—and are quite common in those incarnations. Barbara Kipfer, _Dictionary of American Slang_, 4th edition (2007) has six entries for _dip_ (none of them the one you have in mind) plus separate entries for _dipped_, _dippo_, _dippy_, _dipshit_, _dipso_, _dipsy_, _dipsy-do_, _dispsy-doodle_, and _dipwad_, plus the phrase _dip one's wick_. Merriam-Webster, meanwhile, has four entries for _dip_ comprising 30 distinct meanings, only one of them slang (according to MW). So good luck.

Comment: @WS2 the original sense of "duck" is the "under water" sense, which is why certain water birds are called ducks.

Comment: Are you sure that dip has the meaning of to leave in American English?  I ask because I am American and my first language is English, but I have never heard this usage.

Comment: Native american speaker here. From the midwest with exposure to California. I've heard it in common usage among those who are about 30-40 years old now.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the relevant entry for *dip* as a verb in J. E. Lighter, *The Random House Historical Dictionary of American Slang*, volume 2 (1994):

> **dip** *v.* ... 2. to hurry away; DUCK. {1984 quot. perh. reflects an independent use.} **1903** Hobart *Out for the Coin* 14: He ... grabbed his lid ... and dipped for the woods. **1984** Toop *Rap Attack* 158 : *Dip*, or *buff*: terms for leaving.

The earlier example, from Hugh McHugh [George Hobart], [*Out for the Coin*](https://books.google.com/books?id=dtQ9AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA14&dq=%22and+dipped+for+the+woods%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjvgYn_0qHOAhVIVWMKHR15ABUQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22and%20dipped%20for%20the%20woods%22&f=false) (1903) reads in context this way:

> "Finally he [Uncle Peter] got so rich that he used to trip and fall over the day's winnings when he tried to lock up shop in the evening. He then decided to build a fort around his rake-off, so he grabbed his lid, shook a day-day to the Street [that is, Wall Street], and dipped for the woods."

As you can see, this book is very free with McHugh's representation of Wall Street lingo of the turn of the century ("shook a day-day" seems to mean "bade adieu").

The 1984 quotation is from David Toop, [*The Rap Attack: African Jive to New York Hip Hop*](https://books.google.com/books?id=fX6fAAAAMAAJ&q=%22Rap+Attack%22+%22dip+or+buff%22&dq=%22Rap+Attack%22+%22dip+or+buff%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjP2arT2qHOAhVH0mMKHdmDCjIQ6AEIHjAA) (1984):

> *Breakout*, *dip*, or *buff*: all are terms for leaving. *Example:* 'Fellas I'm gonna breakout because I have to meet my woman.'

Tom Dalzell, [*Flappers 2 Rappers: American Youth Slang*](https://books.google.com/books?id=DsFIAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA197&dq=to+leave+is+to+Audi+5000%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj36v7I5qHOAhVCy2MKHZ-rBMwQ6AEIPjAG#v=onepage&q=to%20leave%20is%20to%20Audi%205000%22&f=false) (1996) identifies *dip* as one of many terms in 1980s and early 1990s "hip hop & rap" slang used to signify that one is leaving:

> To leave is to **Audi 5000, bill, blow, book, boogie, bounce, break, break north, buff, bux one, clock out, dip, flex, ghost, haul ass, jet, motor, outie, parlay, step off, swayze,** or **tear up**.

Dalzell notes that in the hiphop slang of the same era, *dip* (along with *dap* and *dope*) could also mean "Good with a fashionable twist," The term *dip* then crossed over into white/interracial U.S. youth slang in the 1990s, as Dalzell memorializes in this exceedingly brief entry:

> **dip** To leave

And finally, Tony Thorne, [*Dictionary of Contemporary Slang*](https://books.google.com/books?id=5He9AgAAQBAJ&pg=PA128&dq=%22dip+out+vb+American%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiEienz6KHOAhVO0GMKHf4_Cd4Q6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22dip%20out%20vb%20American%22&f=false), fourth edition (2014) has this for dip:

> **dip (out)** *vb American* to depart, leave. A vogue term from black street slang of the 1990s. The variant form 'do the dip' has also been recorded. A variety of euphemisms (like its contemporaries **bail**, **book**, **jam** and **jet**) for 'run away' are essential to the argot of gang members and their playground imitators.

None of these sources suggests how the word *dip* (in the sense of leave) arose in the first place. I share Lighter's skepticism that the 1980s hiphop use drew directly from Wall Street jargon of 80 years before, particularly since none of the slang dictionaries covering the period in-between record any contemporaneous use of *dip* in the relevant sense.

Having said that, I can imagine that either the 1903 Wall Street *dip*, the 1984 hiphop *dip*, or both, independently, might have arisen simply from a truncation of the verb *depart*. Unfortunately, this is pure speculation in my part. I haven't found any reference work that attempts to link the slang word *dip* to the well-respected standard English word *depart*.

Comment: The 1903 example, *dipped into [the woods]*, could be paralleled with the French *plonger dans [les bois]* (*plonger* being more like dive, plunge), which remains common - but the French doesn't have this generic slang meaning for *plonger*.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Green’s Dictionary of Slang](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/axvetjq) the etymology of dip meaning to leave is unknown, but it is  worth noting that a similar  sense (to go) has been present in  Australian slan from early 20th century:

> 1. ***(Aus.) to go.***
>
> - 1911    [Aus]   E. Dyson ‘The Disposal of a Dog’ in Benno and Some of the Push 135: *I’ll dip in here ’n’ buy a sack.*
> - 1953    [Aus]   T.A.G. Hungerford Riverslake 151: Anyway, *I’ll dip over and put this in my room.*

> 2. ***(US black teen) to leave***.
>
> - 1903    [US]    ‘Hugh McHugh’ Out for the Coin 14: *He grabbed his lid, shook a day-to-day to the Street, and dipped for the woods.*
> - 1990    [US]    Eble Campus Sl. Apr. 3: dip – leave.
> - 1995    [US]    L. Stavsky et al. A2Z 28/1: dip, or dip to, or do the dip – 1. v. to leave.
> - 1999    [US]    Dr Dre ‘Still D.R.E.’  Well, hell, me and Snoop, we dipping again.
> - 2020    [US]    S.A. Crosby Blacktop Wasteland 171: Jenny had bailed on him [...] *The day she dipped, they found the dyke chip burnt crispier than grandma’s fried chicken.*

Answer (score 0):

Dan Bron is correct. My mother from the 60s even knew how to dip out! My generation... we used dip or dipping with a nod of the head to signal leaving. I graduated in 1994. Midwest. Maybe my friends and I were weird... but it was our signal system.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site.  This read as a comment, but you could improve your answer with a reference.  Please stick around to take the [tour] and read the [FAQ].

Answer (score -1):

I'd say this is just an evolution of the word "duck". As in "Lets duck" which means lets get out of here. Ducking and Dipping seems pretty similar and someone creatively decided to use dip instead of duck and it stuck.

Comment: Please try to give a source for your answer. This site strives to provide objective answers. Find out about good answers in the [Help Center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score -1):

I fear we are looking for an etymological reason where we should instead be looking for a behavioral explanation.

In this case, I believe the dip is actually referring to a bow or curtsey, such as would have traditionally rendered before leaving a formal gathering. We also still have common usage of bowing out of things.

Answer (score -1):

[image: Capone's speakeasy flyer]

‘Dip your Bill’ 1920s slang used on this Speakeasy notice.

Comment: I'd assume that "dip their bill" was a slang reference to [taking a drink](https://lingomash.com/slang-meanings/73704/slang-meaning-of-dip-the-bill) rather than leaving anything.

Comment: This notice is a modern novelty item that sprinkles 1920s slang words into a narrative that aims to re-create actual contemporaneous speech (a much harder task). Its historical accuracy depends on the anonymous author's knowledge, skill, and scrupulousness, about which we can only guess. Certain details (such as the spelling "boozehound" for a term that in the 1920s seems normally to have been spelled "booze hounds" or "booze-hounds") and the spelling "tiger milk" for what would have been spelled "tiger's milk" or "tigers' milk") do not inspire confidence even at the level of individual terms.

Answer (score -2):

In AmE "dip" has assumed the present day meaning of 'leaving'/ 'getting out' or, simply, of being vanished in colloquial usage. We know not how it has so evolved or at all it meant as such. What We suggest is a pure guess work.

In our part of the world (India) we take

- holy dip in water
- dip cattle in treated water
- use onion dip
- even dip the flag in honour.

It is this meaning of 'dip' that does the trick. At the time of  dipping, what is dipped is removed from the sight. In our day to day parlance, (Street talk) we streach this meaning of 'dip' to its illogical extreme to mean 'playing truant' or staying away from somewhere.
English knew no boundaries and perhaps, it will ever know . Probably, it this use of ours that has sneaked into your usages. Who knows!

Answer (score -2):

While also a bit of a stretch, This might answer your question. Dip is a thinner form of tobacco and the phase "Let's dip" could come from people being made to go outside to smoke/chew etc. and not contaminate homes with the overpowering smell.

"Let's go outside and smoke some dip," shortened to "Let's go outside and dip," to, "Let's dip." meaning, to go outside, and finally, to leave.